# If statement returning undefined but still passing the correct returned value on? Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

This script works... But it doesn't make sense.

**Context** I'm very new to js... This script changes element opacity one by one, when trying to implement a hover "override" I had to find a way to convert the hovered elements id to the index used by the script that rotates through. That way the flow resets/resumes from the hovered element.

**Problem** My issue is at the if statement converting the ids to index #s in the "idConvertNum" func. The if statement values all return undefined even though the ids are the same as the string values!? Only the else(4) passes through. The weird part is that the "i" receiving the converted index receives the correct value?? ... I, am so confused.

Thanks so much, if you have any tips they're greatly appreciated!

html

```
<!--main content start-->
<div id="main-container">
<div id="iconGrid">
    <div id="arrowText1" class="arrow">→</div>
    <div id="arrowText2" class="arrow">→</div>
    <div id="arrowText3" class="arrow">→</div>
    <div id="arrowText4" class="arrow">→</div>
    <i id="suppDirIcon"><img onmouseover="onHover(id)" onmouseleave="offHover(id)" id="icon1" class="iconFlow" src="/assets/supplier directory icon.png" alt="supplier directory"></i>
    <i id="videoMeetIcon"><img onmouseover="onHover(id)" onmouseleave="offHover(id)" id="icon2" class="iconFlow" src="/assets/video meeting icon.png" alt="video meetings"></i>
    <i id="factInspIcon"><img onmouseover="onHover(id)" onmouseleave="offHover(id)" id="icon3" class="iconFlow" src="/assets/inspection icon.png" alt="factory inspections"></i>
    <i id="orderSupIcon"><img onmouseover="onHover(id)" onmouseleave="offHover(id)" id="icon4" class="iconFlow" src="/assets/supervision icon.png" alt="order supervision"></i>
    <i id="payProtIcon"><img onmouseover="onHover(id)" onmouseleave="offHover(id)" id="icon5" class="iconFlow" src="/assets/pay icon.png" alt="payment protection"></i>
    <div id="suppDirText" class="iconFlowText">Supplier directory</div>
    <div id="videoMeetText" class="iconFlowText">Video meetings</div>
    <div id="factInspText" class="iconFlowText">Factory inspections</div>
    <div id="orderSupText" class="iconFlowText">Order supervision</div>
    <div id="payProtText" class="iconFlowText">Payment Protection</div>
</div>
<hr class="dividerLine">
```

Javascript

```
var iconText = [];
var iconImg = [];
var time = 5000;

// icon subtext
iconText[0] = document.getElementById("suppDirText");
iconText[1] = document.getElementById("videoMeetText");
iconText[2] = document.getElementById("factInspText");
iconText[3] = document.getElementById("orderSupText");
iconText[4] = document.getElementById("payProtText");
// icons
iconImg[0] = document.getElementById("icon1");
iconImg[1] = document.getElementById("icon2");
iconImg[2] = document.getElementById("icon3");
iconImg[3] = document.getElementById("icon4");
iconImg[4] = document.getElementById("icon5");
// starting indexes
var i = 0;
var j = iconImg.length - 1;
// converts id of hovered element to associated index
function idConvertNum(id){
    if (id == "icon1"){ return 0;}
    else if (id == "icon2"){ return 1;}
    else if (id == "icon3"){ return 2;}
    else if (id == "icon4"){ return 3;} // all undefined ??? the ids are == to the strings? why?
    else { return 4;} // always returns 4, no matter which element is hovered ???
}
// resets flow to hovered element
function onHover(id){ // passes element id through html "onmouseenter"
    clearInterval(iconTimer); // stops interval
    changeIconBack(j); // resets all to default
    i = idConvertNum(id); // sets i to index value converted from id

                console.log(idConvertNum()) // always returns 4 but script works as intended?

    if (i==0){ // pairs j to new i
        j = iconImg.length - 1;
    } else {
        j = i - 1;
    };
    iconFlow(); // calls update func
}
// continues flow from last hovered element
function offHover(id){ // passes element id through html "onmouseleave"
    i = idConvertNum(id); // sets i to index value converted from id
    if (i==0){ // pairs j to new i
        j = iconImg.length - 1;
    } else {
        j = i - 1;
    };
    iconFlow(); // calls update func
    iconTimer = setInterval(iconFlow, time); // starts interval flow
}

function changeIcon(i){ // if making changes, remember to match .css file styles
    iconText[i].style.opacity = "1";
    iconImg[i].style.opacity = "1";
    iconImg[i].style.width="90px";
}
function changeIconBack(j){ // if making changes, remember to match .css file styles
    iconText[j].style.opacity = "0.4";
    iconImg[j].style.opacity = "0.4";
    iconImg[j].style.width="70px";
}

function iconFlow(){
    changeIconBack(j)
    changeIcon(i);
    j = i;
    i = (i + 1) % iconImg.length; // used modular arithmetic
}

var iconTimer = setInterval(iconFlow, time);
window.onload=iconFlow;
```

Comment: I started to go through your code, but frankly it needs to be completely reworked, You don't need one function to set styles and another to revert them back to their original values and one function to handle hovering and another for non hovering that both do largely the same thing. If you replace all this extra clutter and don't rely on `id`'s in the first place, the code will be much simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I spent a lot of time looking for code examples providing similar results so this is sort of what I mashed up with my thought process and information available to me. Do you have any more specific advice on accomplishing this more efficiently? In the mean time I'll try to simplify it, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should log `i` or`idConvertNum(id)` instead of the result of calling `idConvertNum` with no arguments, as that will always return the default value of `4`.

```
function onHover(id){ // passes element id through html "onmouseenter"
    clearInterval(iconTimer); // stops interval
    changeIconBack(j); // resets all to default
    i = idConvertNum(id); // sets i to index value converted from id

    console.log(i)

    if (i==0){ // pairs j to new i
        j = iconImg.length - 1;
    } else {
        j = i - 1;
    };
    iconFlow(); // calls update func
}
```

Comment: wow... I don't know how I missed that. Thanks, you probably saved me 5 hours of scratching my head.

Comment: @Ostnic No problem.